# How to find out if buildbot is building?

Tags: python, buildbot

I'm trying to write a Python script which automatically restarts buildbot if nothing is building. How can the script check to see if there's anything being built?

Comment: What do you mean "nothing is building"? Buildbot runs builds according to configured schedulers: for example by timer, by interactive user request, by hook after new commits arrived, etc. So Buildbot doesn't build if it not being told to build in one or another way.

Comment: Yes we have multiple users who have builds going on at various times. If I modify master.cfg then I have to restart buildbot in order for the new factories to show up in the web page. But I don't want to restart buildbot if someone has a build going on because it might interrupt their build.

Comment: You could try a 'reconfig'. It's re-reading the config and does a non-disruptive restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, you should:

- Create systemd (or any other) script for buildbot master, to run it continuous after start-up and after failing/exiting ([worker example](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot-contrib/blob/master/master/contrib/systemd/buildbot.service))
- In corresponding buildstep initiate master graceful shutdown with `buildbot stop --clean --no-wait`
- init-service would re-start bb-master